# Not detecting HDD after installing Ubuntu 12.04!

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, hard-drive, format

After installing Ubuntu 12.04, which I'm using right now and it works great, my extra hard drive was detected the first time I turned on my computer but then it does not show anymore on my Home Folder, when I run the Disk Utility says that has a few errors but when I try to fix it, says that hard drive is busy and cannot do anything else.

I've unmounted it and mounted again but nothing happens.

Do you know what can be going on? Cause the first time that I was able to see my hard drive it had all the files I have, but I don't know if deleting the partition will format the whole hard drive or just the ubuntu files.

THANKS in advance!

BY THE WAY, I'm new to Ubuntu... :S

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is whether your drive is listed in `fstab`, which is a file that automagically mounts filesystems when your computer boots. You can see the contents of this file by running any of the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
sudo vim /etc/fstab        #    [esc], then ":q!" to quit
sudo nano /etc/fstab       #     CTRL+X then enter to quit
```

Each line is a filesystem. Look for your external drive by looking at the field after `UUID=XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX` it will look like `/media/NameOfYourDrive` unless you told the installer otherwise. Copy the UUID somewhere.

Next, check that the UUID of your filesystem matches that. You can find the UUID of all the filesystems Ubuntu knows about by running:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label
```

Check that the UUID you found in `fstab` matches the UUID that points to your drive. (i.e., the UUID points to `/dev/sdb1` and so does the label from `/dev/disk/by-label`, `/dev/sdb1` could be anything)

If those match then go back to `fstab` and check that the filesystem type is correct (ntfs for windows drives, ext for ubuntu ones). If it is anything else, copy the line from `fstab` and put it in your question

Comment: By doing the above as you suggest does show that there are two drives and the UUID for both match. I have two HDDs in my computer and I still can't see them in file system.

Comment: One important fact I think you missed is that Hard drives don't have UUIDs. Filesystems do :) Try running `sudo mount` and look at the last few entries. They should look like `/dev/sdb1 on /media/drivename type ntfs` or something like that. If you don't see it try `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` if it is `ext` formatted or `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt` and then go check out `/mnt` for your files